# Xdebug and PhpStorm cannot use F7 to step debugging

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

- PhpStorm 2020.3
- Xdebug 2.7 / 2.81 / 2.98 / 3.01
- PHP 7.3 CGI/FastCGI
- Windows 10

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

You can have a breakpoint, but after pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>, the code does not jump to the next line of the breakpoint, and the program exits directly.

[image: This is a picture of the fault:]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322810/phpstorm-xdebug-unable-to-step-through-debugging -- you have posted the same 30 mins ago. Are you still having issues after upgrading to latest Xdebug version? You should have commented there instead of making new question.

Comment: Yes, I used 3.0.1 and 2.98 xdebug.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with my use of windows?

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows. I'm using it on Windows, works just fine. You said you have tried it with Xdebug 3.0.1 -- v3 uses DIFFERENT config params than v2.

Comment: Anyway: 1) please post Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured in a same way as you are trying to debug (be it CLI or a web page) 2) Please enable Xdebug log, try to debug and share the log.

Comment: If you are definitely using Xdebug 2.9.8 or v3.0.1 .. then the best guess so far is missing/wrong path mappings (IDE cannot map debugged file to the file in the project). Xdebug log + showing what file you are trying to debug (the file path) should shed some light on this.

Comment: My code runs locally and does not need to configure mapping.

Comment: Yes, xdebug 2.x and 3.x have different configuration styles, both of which I have used.

Comment: *"My code runs locally and does not need to configure mapping"* Not always true -- when symlink/join point is involved. Thing is: PHP/Xdebug works with final (resolved) path while IDE works with the path as is. ANYWAY: it's just a guess (most common thing in my experience). Need to the see the actual details (e.g. could be some nuances that you think are not important etc)

Comment: Enable extra logging on PhpStorm side: it can show if it's related to path mapings or not: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html. Check that link in full anyway.

Comment: BTW: PhpStorm has 2 "Break on first line ..." debug related options -- if you disable them both -- will IDE still be stopping at the breakpoint? Will it stop if your breakpoint will be set on `$b = 2` line instead? At what line?

Comment: It won't stop on the line $b = 2.

Comment: The code I opened in IDE is the actual running code, so there is no need to configure path mapping

Comment: I replaced phpstorm with vscode so that it can be used normally.

Comment: *"It won't stop on the line $b = 2"* That looks like an issue with breakpoints to me (the typical behaviour). Anyway: I cannot advise anything more without any logs etc. It could be some simple thing .. but nothing more concrete comes into my mind and there is no point of doing wild guessing...